# jquery: .show() unhides always hidden elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a searchbar that removes all Ids that dont match what the user has typed. The Ids are equal to the label on the little box.

This is the start view:

[image]

This is how the boxes are created:

```
<table class="table-fullWitdh centered">
    @{
        int counter = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < Model.cats.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (counter % 6 == 0)
            {
                <tr class="centered"></tr>
            }
            <td class="centered" id="@Model.cats[i].DisplayValue.ToLower()" name="isCat"> @*take display value as id to remove from search *@
                @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.cats[i].DisplayValue)
                @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.cats[i].Id)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(y => y.cats[i].IsChecked, new { @id=@Model.cats[i].Id, @class = "checkbox" })
                <label for=@Model.cats[i].Id>@Model.cats[i].DisplayValue</label>
            </td>
            counter++;
        }
    }
</table>
```

Please note, that there is a checkbox as well but this checkbox is always hidden:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Now when I type something in my searchbar I fire a function that basically takes what the user has input and shows all containing IDs:

```
$('.inputhere').on('input', function () {
     
    // first hide everything
    if(this.value == ''){
        jQuery("td[name='isCat']").each(function () {
            $(this).show()
        });
    } else{
        jQuery("td[name='isCat']").each(function () {
            $(this).hide()
        });

    }
   
    // then show elements where id contains
    $('*[id*=' + this.value.toLowerCase() + ']').each(function (i, obj) {
        $(this).show()
    });
});
```

The logic itself works. THis is what happens when I typ "Bau" which exists in a few of these boxe:

[image]

Only boxes that contain the words "bau" are shown, but the hidden checkbox now becomes visible... Only on a few elements, but ofc this is an issue.
Is there maybe a better way of handling this or is it just my mistake?

Best,

J

Comment: `.show()` *effectively* (after some animation) does:  `$(this).style("display:block")` - ie sets the inline style.  This has higher precedence over your css so shows the element.  Having said that: I can't see where you're calling `.show()`.

Comment: damnit, i copied the wrong code, please check again...

Comment: Without looking too closely, one option would be to add an "except" class, eg `alwayshidden { display:none; }` then exclude these: `$(":input:not(.alwayshidden)")` for example

Comment: yeah, i just tried that and that always works. thank you my friend! post as answer and ill accept

Comment: Can only assume that this is due to the `// then show elements where id contains` part - your table cell ids, and those of the checkboxes, seem to be identical or partially overlap here? Then add `:not(input)` to the selector you are using there, so that it leaves all input fields alone in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

change `*[id*=` to `td[id*=`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".inputhere").on("input", function() {
    // first hide everything
    if (this.value == "") {
      jQuery("td[name='isCat']").each(function() {
        $(this).show();
      });
    } else {
      jQuery("td[name='isCat']").each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });
    }

    // then show elements where id contains
    $("td[id*=" + this.value.toLowerCase() + "]").each(function(i, obj) {
      $(this).show();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.centered {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

table {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="inputhere" id="inputhere" name="inputhere" placeholder="Search" type="text" />
<table class="table-fullWitdh centered">
  <tr class="centered">
    <td class="centered" id="quick" name="isCat">
      <input type="hidden" name="test" id="test" /><input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" />
      <input type="checkbox" value="chk" name="chk" id="chk" />
      <label for="id">quick</label>
    </td>
    <td class="centered" id="brown" name="isCat">
      <input type="hidden" name="test1" id="test1" /><input type="hidden" name="id1" id="id1" />
      <input type="checkbox" value="chk1" name="chk1" id="chk1" />
      <label for="id1">brown</label>
    </td>
    <td class="centered" id="fox" name="isCat">
      <input type="hidden" name="test2" id="test2" /><input type="hidden" name="id2" id="id2" />
      <input type="checkbox" value="chk2" name="chk2" id="chk2" />
      <label for="id2">fox</label>
    </td>
    <td class="centered" id="jumps" name="isCat">
      <input type="hidden" name="test3" id="test3" /><input type="hidden" name="id3" id="id3" />
      <input type="checkbox" value="chk3" name="chk3" id="chk3" />
      <label for="id3">jumps</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```